# My program don't show the content of array. Don't know if my program reversed the characters

Tags: c++, arrays, reverse

I'd like to revers characters from one array and copy them to the new one, but it doesn't work. Here is my code in c++ (I'm beginner):

```
char *str1 = "ppC";

int sumofchar = 0;
while(*str1 != '\0') // THIS LOOP ADD NUMBERS OF CHARACTERS IN ARRAY
{
         sumofchar++;
         str1++; 
}
cout << sumofchar << endl; // THIS WRITES NUMBERS OF CHARACTERS (3)

int placeInArr = sumofchar-1; 

  //placeInArr is the last place (exept of '\0') in array 

int walker = 0;
char strNew[sumofchar]; //New array with 3 characters

while(placeInArr!=-1)  // THIS LOOP SHOULD WRITES CHARACTERS IN THE NEW ONE
{
    strNew[walker] = str1[placeInArr]; // In the first time: strNew[0]=str1[2]
    walker++;
    placeInArr--;
}

cout << strNew << endl; // This should write the new array with reverse characters, but it doesn't work.
```

Comment: why not use `std::strlen()` on char pointers? Even better: `std::string::size()`?

Comment: Are you modifying the pointee of `str1`? I hope not; use `const char *`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all this code

```
char strNew[sumofchar]; //New array with 3 characters
```

is not C++ compliant. The size of an array shall be a constant expression.

Also string literals in C++ have types of constant arrays. So you have to write

```
const char *str1 = "ppC";
```

Nevertheless the main problem of your code is that 1) the size of the array shall be greater

```
char strNew[sumofchar + 1]; //New array with 4 characters
```

2)and the array has to have the terminating zero. So after the loop add one more statement

```
while(placeInArr!=-1)  // THIS LOOP SHOULD WRITES CHARACTERS IN THE NEW ONE
{
    strNew[walker] = str1[placeInArr]; // In the first time: strNew[0]=str1[2]
    walker++;
    placeInArr--;
}

strNew[walker] = '\0';
```

3) before the copy operation you have to write

```
str1 -= sumofchar;
```

By the way if you need simply to output the array in the reverse order you could use standard algorithm std::reverse_copy. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
   char s[] = "ppC";

   std::reverse_copy( s, s + sizeof( s ) - 1, std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout ) );
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You incremented your original pointer to your string, therefor `str1[2]` isn't what you think it is anymore.

Either use `strlen` or an additional variable for counting, or pointer arithmetic if you really want to operate on the changed `char*`. Note that you would usually use a `std::string` instead of a `char*` when operating on strings.

#### Example using `strlen`

```
int sumofchar = std::strlen(str1);
```

#### Example using an additional `char*`

```
int sumofchar = 0;
for(char * t = str1; *t != '\0'; ++t)
{
         sumofchar++;
}
```

#### Example using pointer arithmetic

```
int placeInArr = -1;
```

(Don't use that one, as it's rather obfuscated.

Comment: @TheOneWhoAsks: You're welcome, however, this answer only concerns this single problem, there are others with your code, which are concerned by Vlad.

Answer (score 1):

How to do this very easily using `std::string`:

```
std::string str1 {"ppC"};

std::string str2 {str1.crbegin(),str1.crend()};
```

And done. You should always prefer the standard library over handwritten code, it is much less error prone, easier to read and probably more efficient.

Comment: Yes, but you know, I'm the beginner so I avoid to use standard library.

Comment: This is not a very good idea imo.
The standard library is like the best thing of c++. It takes away tons of work from you.
You should know it really well.
Plus it always does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @TheOneWhoAsks: And yet I haven't seen a carpenter apprentice working without his/her tools, after he/she learned the theory.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code 'stops' on first while loop:

```
while(*str1 != '\0') // THIS LOOP ADD NUMBERS OF CHARACTERS IN ARRAY
{
         sumofchar++;
         str1++; 
}
```

You just can't do pointer aritmatics `str1++;` - here according to code you moved you pointer and it points now to some (unknow) part of memory so there can be some trash value and probably this you will see when compile this code. 
Working solution of your code could looks like this(only my version):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char* str1 = "ppC";

    int sumofchar = std::strlen(str1);
    std::cout << sumofchar << std::endl; 

    char* strNew = new char[sumofchar];

    for (int i = 0; i < sumofchar; ++i)
    {
        strNew[i] = str1[sumofchar - i - 1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sumofchar; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << strNew[i];
    }
}
```

I didn't use while-loops but you can do this if you just want :)